# base_url () function is not working ( Code ignitor)

Tags: php, model-view-controller, href

im new to php and recently im trying to load my html and css file into the code ignitor . Thus, my website wont load when i try to link between pages using href, id be so grateful if anyone can point out my mistakes, thankyou

this one is the view part where i want to link between pages

```
 <header>
    <nav>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="<?= base_url()?> signup">Sign ups</a></li>    
          </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

this one is the signup controller

```
<?php

class signup extends extends CI_controller{

public function index()
{
    $this -> load -> view ('header');
    $this -> load -> view ('signup_view');
    $this -> load -> view ('footer');

}

}
```

Comment: Help: open dev tools and check final URL. I see there a typo.

Comment: thankyou for helping me out sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like CI 2.x - if it's CI 3+ you need to titlecase your controller like in my code below. However, your issue is not loading the `url helper`. You can place it in the construct of your controller or right in the `index` function

```
<?php
class Signup extends extends CI_controller{

function __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->helper('url');
}

public function index() {
// ...
```

That will enable it in that controller, but you can enable it globally by placing this in your `config/autoload.php` file:

```
$autoload['helpers'] = array('url');
```